# horizontal alignment of form fields

Tags: html, css, css-float

how to make the city state zip to align in the same line
i reduced the width but its not working
how to fix it

```
<div class="">
   <label class="" for="">City</label><input style="width: 54px;" type="text">
   <label class="" for="">State</label><input style="width: 54px;" type="text">
   <label class="" for="">Zip</label><input style="width: 54px;" type="text" >
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VXXPC/19/

Comment: Wrap each label/input in a div and float the div left.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your labels are `display: block`. Use `display: inline-block` like you have with the fields.

This took me all of about 10 seconds to realise with the browser developer tools. Hitting [F12] in most modern browsers (FF requires installation of FireBug) launches the bundled developer tools. Here you can inspect the offending element(s) and see the CSS that effects the element(s).

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VXXPC/22/). I've applied a class to the parent div `inline-fields`. In the CSS I've added:

```
.inline-fields label {
    display: inline-block;
}
```